# Grid line only on data point for scratter points

Tags: charts, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-chart

I need to draw x & y intercepts for all data points in a scratter chart. I went through major and minor grid lines. But it could not be my perfect solution.

Like the image below:

[The sample image with x and y intercepts only on data points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWrjm.png)

Comment: Please share the code you've written so far.

Comment: @CarstenFranke http://jsfiddle.net/inikolova/UJkkb/2/  We can use this code where it intercepts between the points but we need to intercept the point and axis instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the render function of the chart to draw the horizontal and vertical lines on the chart surface. In the following demo, I name the x and y axes so that in the render function I can use the getAxis() method along with slot and range. See **[DOCS](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/methods/getaxis)**.

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/jQvyPo)**

```
var data = [[0.67, 5.4], [2.2, 2], [3.1, 3]];
$("#chart").kendoChart({
  series: [{
    type: "scatter",
        data: data,
        markers: {size: 16},
  }],
  yAxis: { name: "value",   majorGridLines: {visible: false } },
  xAxis: { name: "category",    majorGridLines: {visible: false } },
  render: function(e){
    var chart = e.sender;
    var yAxis = chart.getAxis("value");
    var xAxis = chart.getAxis("category");
        //iterate each point on the chart
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            //vertical line
            var valRange = yAxis.range();
        var valSlot = yAxis.slot(valRange.min, valRange.max);
            var point = data[i];            
            var catSlot = xAxis.slot(point[0]);
            var path = new kendo.drawing.Path({
             stroke: {color: "#B3BDBD", width: 1}
            }).moveTo(catSlot.origin.x + catSlot.size.width/2, valSlot.origin.y)
                .lineTo(catSlot.origin.x + catSlot.size.width/2, valSlot.bottomRight().y);

            chart.surface.draw(path); 
            //horizontal line
            var ySlot = yAxis.slot(point[1]);
            var xRange = xAxis.range();
            var xSlot = xAxis.slot(xRange.min, xRange.max);
            var pathH = new kendo.drawing.Path({
             stroke: {color: "#B3BDBD", width: 1}
            }).moveTo(xSlot.origin.x,  ySlot.origin.y + ySlot.size.width/2)
                .lineTo(xSlot.bottomRight().x, ySlot.origin.y + ySlot.size.width/2);

            chart.surface.draw(pathH); 
        }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can we add the line under the points? I know line render will be the last. But am curious to prepend or something to make underlay.

Comment: @AjayDev, to do that I believe you would need to play with the chart SVG directly. You can inspect it in the browser dev tools and see about moving the paths to the correct group.

Comment: I just look into this. Meanwhile, thank you so much for the solution. This is a perfect one for me.

Comment: @AjayDev, I have updated the demo to draw the lines behind the points:  https://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/jQvyPo

Comment: @ezankar ,  Modifying the opacity seems very hacking. It might have unintended side effects too.Can we prefer using some attribute that the renderer ignores?

Comment: @AjayDev, go for it! let us know what you come up with.

Comment: @ezankar ,  Since the render paths fall under direct svg, lets select like below                                                                                                             
           `let $charts = $(chart.surface.element); 
            let $paths = $charts.find('svg > path'); 
            //let element = $paths.detach(); 
            $charts.find('g').eq(0).prepend($paths); `

Comment: @LazyCoder , Nice! Just change your last line to $charts.find('g > g').eq(0).prepend(element); (Updated CodePen:   https://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/jQvyPo). The reason I used Opacity for specificity is because the chart has other paths depending on selected features. So you might end up detaching the wrong path... For this example, every path directly below SVG works.

Comment: @LazyCoder , or to put it in first "g" use append instead of prepend as there are already 2 paths there that must stay behind.